# android - can't get exclusive audio focus

Tags: android, audio, alarmmanager, android-audiomanager

While requesting audio focus (`AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_EXCLUSIVE`) from audio manager, I am getting `Invalid duration hint, audio focus request denied` error.

This app is an alarm clock and I wouldn't want notifications to cut into alarm stream, that's why I am trying to get exclusive audio focus.

Here is the code:

```
int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(
    onAudioFocusChangeListener,
    AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,
    AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_EXCLUSIVE);
```

So how can I get exclusive audio focus?

Comment: Which device and Android version are you testing on?

Comment: @Michael HTC Desire SV, android 4.0.4

Comment: `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_EXCLUSIVE` was added in API level 19 (Android 4.4). Android 4.0.4 is API level 15.